# How do i display the username who posted the comment?

Tags: php, html, comments

So far I am only able to display the username who is logged in at the moment, therefore, all the comments will be posted by the username who is logged in at the moment :(

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo '<div class="media my-3">
    <img src="img/userprofile.png" width="54px" class="mr-3" alt="...">
    <div class="media-body">
      <p class="font-weight-bold my-0">'.$_SESSION['username'].' at '. $thread_time.'</p>
      <h5 class="mt-0">
        <a class="text-dark" href="thread.php?threadid=' . $id . '">'. $title .'</a>
      </h5>
      '. $desc .'
    </div>
  </div>';
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Do you save a userid or username along with the comment when saving it?

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly,  Thank you, i will take a look soon! Sorry i am new to this :x

Comment: Hello @brombeer! Under comment in phpmyadmin, i did created a "comment_by" if this is what you are referring to? sorry!!

Comment: Wherever you get $title and $desc from, you need to also get the author; since you don't show any of that code, there is no way for anyone you tell you more than that

Answer (score 0):

i think your using a username session value who is logged in....you need to to save the userId in the table while submitting the comments form and use the userId to show the username.